# SLComposeServiceViewController preview view doesn't show up

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to use `SLComposeServiceViewController` inside my app as a UI for composing and posting a message to my backend.

However, if I override `loadPreviewView` and return a view as stated in the documentation, that view doesn't show up.

This is my code:

```
@interface ComposeViewController : SLComposeServiceViewController
@end


@implementation ComposeViewController
- (UIView *)loadPreviewView {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return v;
}
@end
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Why is my red view not showing up?

Comment: One thing I tried was to hold a strong reference on the custom view. But it doesn't help.

Comment: It works if my custom view is a UIImageView that has a non-null image set.