# SLComposeServiceViewController layout fail iPad when using preview

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I want to use SLComposeServiceViewController inside my app as a UI for composing and posting a message to my backend.

I override `loadPreviewView` and return a UIImageView to display an image to be attached to my post.

This works well on the iPhone, but if I run the same code on the iPad, the layout gets messed up:
The height of the textfield appears to be set to the height of the preview view, which might be 0 if the image is not set.

Does anyone have a workaround, or a hint if I am doing something wrong?

As a demo, I have set a 10x10 image:

iPhone (looks alright):
[image]

iPad (layout messed up): 
[image]

Side note: I have run into trouble with `SLComposeServiceViewController` [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37542359/921573).

Comment: As a workaround, I am now setting a transparent 1x80 px placeholder image when creating the attachmentsView. It fixes the layout glitch.

Comment: Not trying to answer the question, but on iOS 10 does this just show a black background instead of the transparent you see here? That's all i get when doing the same thing.

Comment: Did you find a more long-term solution for this? It's a bugger!

Comment: @SAHM I went with the 1px hack and never looked at that code ever since... Still the same bug with current iOS?

Comment: Yup, with the iPad. I tried your solution and it works, so I guess it will be good enough for me too. Thanks!